# Groovy Graphing Library/Tool?

Tags: groovy, graph

I'm looking for a tool/library for Groovy that will graph points on a graph. I thought that SwingXBuilder might do the trick, but it looks like that's only used for graphing functions.

I'm looking for something that will allow me to see specific X and Y values on a line graph... Does anyone know of anything like this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/). Although it may seem as an overkill but I remember myself finding no worthy alternatives when I was looking for a similar thing about a year ago.

Comment: +1 There are a couple if groovy wrappers for jfreechart around, but they seen to be either dead or mia :-/